# Why does a syntax error show up near <MyGrid> when I run my kv file?

Tags: python, kivy

I just started trying out kivy developing and ran into a problem. When I try to run a simple kivy file with a corresponding python file, it emits a syntax error. does anyone know why this happened? FYI I'm using Atom IDE with python 3.8.3, when I ran kivy based on python, it worked flawlessly, but when I try to run a rewritten kv code, it won't run.

Here's the python source code:

```py
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget


class MyGrid(Widget):
    pass


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyGrid()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

...and the kv code:

```
< MyGrid >
    Label:
        text: "example text"
```

Error details:

```
  File "C:\Users\ljhub\Code Storage\Python Projects\my.kv", line 1
    <MyGrid>
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0):

The corrected kv file should be as below:

```
<MyGrid>:
    Label:
        text: "example text"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a colon after any declaration in kv language.
such as:

```
<MyGrid>:
```

or

```
Label:
```